# $a\odot b = ab+a+b$ over $\Bbb Z$ no zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Define the operations $\oplus$ and $\odot$ on $\Bbb Z$ by $a\oplus b = a+b-1$ and $a\odot b = ab+a+b$. Prove that $(\Bbb Z,\odot,\oplus)$ is an integral domain.

Surely they first want me to prove its a ring, so I'll just take that for granted here.

I just want to show that it is an integral domain, given that it is a ring here:

So we need to show that $a\odot b=0\implies a=0$ or $b=0$ I imagine. Okay, so:

$ab+a+b=0$, then if $ab=0$, since $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain, it follows that either $a=0$ or $b=0$ and we are done. So assume not, let $ab\ne 0$, then $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$ and we get $ab+a+b=0 \implies a=b=-2$ as the only valid solution when $ab\ne 0$.

I.e we have shown:

$a\odot b=0 \implies a=b=-2$ or $ab=0\implies a=0$ or $b=0$. Doesn't that mean in the case that $a=b=-2$ that this isn't an integral domain?

We have zero divisor $-2\odot -2=4-4=0$

Comment: You need to first figure out what the 0 is for the ring.  0 isn't always 0.

Comment: That is not a ring. Note that 
$$ 1 \oplus 1 = 1, \quad 1 \odot 1 = 3 $$
as we have
$$ 3 \oplus 3 = 6 - 1 = 5 $$
we have
$$ (1 \oplus 1) \odot 1 = 3 \ne 5 = (1 \odot 1) \oplus (1 \odot 1) $$

Comment: Isn't it $a\oplus b = a+b+1$ ?

Comment: It's pretty clear that this isn't a ring, so I'm not sure what you're asking?

Comment: @martini It is a ring, it is just a ring with different elements as the identity. (It is a ring isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, in fact.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews rings are distributive, which is the property he has shown to be broken (it doesn't matter what he picked to do it)

Comment: If $a \oplus b$ would be defined as suggested by @lhf, everything would be fine. Then $-1$ is the additive identity, and we have a ring isomorphic to $\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Or if the product was defined as $a+b-ab$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If so it's a typo on the lecturers behalf, the notes ask us for $a\oplus b = a+b -1$ and $a\odot b = ab+a+b$. I'll try the problem with the modified operator though

Comment: Note that if $a\oplus b=a+b-1$, the $\oplus$-identity is $1$. Also note that $-2\odot-3=(-2)(-3)+(-2)+(-3)=1$. With the given definition, this doesn't look like an integral domain.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. 
$$ a \odot b = ab + a + b = (a + 1)(b+ 1) - 1. $$
and $(\mathbf Z, +, \cdot)$ is an integral domain.