# Is there a name for this operation? $f(a, b) = a + (1 - a)b$

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a name for this simple operation/function?

$$(a, b) \mapsto a + (1 - a)b$$

The operator takes two real numbers that are between $0$ and $1$, and returns a real number per the formula. Intuitively, it moves the $a$ value towards $1$ by using $b$ as the fraction of the remaining distance to travel. Note that the order of the operands doesn't matter, since $a + (1 - a)b$ rearranges to $b + (1 - b)a$. Another perspective is that it's the sum, minus the product:

$$(a, b) \mapsto a + b - ab$$

So, for example:

- $(0.5, 0.5) \mapsto 0.75$
- $(0.3, 1) \mapsto 1$
- $(0.47, 0.61) \mapsto 0.7933$

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't seen it, but I would interpret it, instead of moving $a$ as moving $b$. This function returns the convex combination of $1$ and $b$ with weights $a$ (and $1-a$).

Comment: The function $f(x,y,t) = (1-t)x+ty$ is usually called *linear interpolation*, also `mix` or `lerp` sometimes. It returns $x$ if $t=0$, $y$ if $t=1$, and some convex combination of $x$ and $y$ if $t\in (0,1)$. You have a special case of $f(b,1,a)$.

Comment: $1-(1-a)(1-b)$, does that help?

Answer (score 3):

Given the [unnamed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720072/)
involution $\,r(x) := 1-x,\,$ then the function (binary operation)
$$ f(a, b) := a + (1 - a)b = a+b-ab $$
is the conjugation of the multiplication operation by the involution $\,r.\,$ That is,
$$ r(f(a,b)) = 1-a-b+ab = (1-a)(1-b) = r(a)r(b). $$
This operation is often used to give an example of a
commutative associative operation that is not either addition
or multiplication. For example
[MSE question 526300](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/526300),
[MSE question 721323](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721323).
Similarly the related operation $\,a+b+ab\,$ in
[MSE question 1509381](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1509381)
where it is denoted by $\,a\odot b\,$ but not otherwise named
is much more common.

---

EDIT (23 Jul 2023): George Boole originally invented his
[eponymous algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)
in the 19th century using variables taking on only values of $0$
or $1$. In his context, they represents logical *False* and *True*,
respectively, the operation $\,r\,$ represents logical negation,
while multiplication represents logical conjunction. The remaining
operator $\,f\,$ represents logical disjunction. You can think of
$\,f\,$ defined on the interval $\,[0,1]\,$ as generalizing this in
the context of [fuzzy logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic).

The answer to your question

> Is there a name for this simple operation/function?

is that it is the *logical disjunction* operation in fuzzy logic.